# Pass bash command a comment to see from pkill

Tags: linux, bash, pkill

I have an aribtrary bash command being run that I want to attach some identifying comment to so that I may pkill it if necessary.

For example:

```
sleep 1000 #uniqueHash93581
pkill -f '#uniqueHash93581'
```

... but the #uniqueHash93581 does not get interpreted, so pkill won't find the process.

Any way to pass this unique hash so that I may pkill the process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bash removes comments before running commands.

---

A workaround with Linux and GNU grep:

Prefix your command with a variable with a unique value

```
ID=uniqueHash93581 sleep 1000
```

Later search this variable to get the PID and kill the process

```
grep -sa ID=uniqueHash93581 /proc/*/environ | cut -d '/' -f 3 | xargs kill
```

Answer (score 1):

`exec` the command in a subshell, and use the `-a` option to give it a recognizable name. For example:

```
$ (exec -a foobar sleep 1000) &
$ ps | grep foobar
893 ttys000    0:00.00 foobar 10
```

Or, just run the job in the background and save its PID.

```
$ sleep 1000 & pid=$!
$ kill "$pid"
```